# Can we get access token from authorization code in passport js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have a client which sends me the Authorization code obtained from an oauth2 authorization end-point. I can create a request from my nodejs back-end code to get the tokens from the token end-point using this authorization code. However, I think that passport js should already have a logic for this, since it can return the tokens in the verify callback function( provided the entire authorization flow is done by passport ). I would like to know if there is a function in passport js that accepts the Authorization code and returns the tokens. I could not find this in the docs. Also tried to debug the passport js code, but with no success :(

Answer (score 5):

If you have a look at [passport oauth2 strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2), what you're describing here:

> I would like to know if there is a function in passport js that accepts the Authorization code and returns the tokens

Is handled by passport. Given the example in the link [1](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2), you should have this configuration for the strategy:

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
  authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
  tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
  clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  // Do whatever here with the profile
 }
));
```

The `callbackURL` is the 'function' you're looking for. Let me explain:

The OAuth2 specification (I'm assuming you're using the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) flow) states that a user is redirected to an Identity Provider (the `authorizationURL`). The identity provider then prompts the user for her credentials and once authenticated, the identity provider will send the user back to your application along with a code. This code should be handled by a callback method that is linked with the callbackURL endpoint. This is how is described in their examples:

```
app.get('/auth/example/callback',
  passport.authenticate('oauth2', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

The callback defined in the strategy should manage what you're trying to achieve.

If this doesn't suit your needs, you can always go monkey patching :) Here is an example that you can try out:

```
'use strict';

var OAuth2 = require('oauth').OAuth2;

function getTokenFromCode (code, clientID, clientSecret, authorizationURL, tokenURL) {
  return () => {
    var oAuth2 = new OAuth2(clientID, config.clientSecret,
    '', config.authorizationURL, config.tokenURL);
    var _getOAuthAccessToken = oAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken;
    oAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken = (code, params, callback) => {
      if (responseType) {
        params.response_type = responseType;
      }
      _getOAuthAccessToken.call(oAuth2, code, params, callback);
    };
    return oAuth2;
  };
}
```

What this code does is the following:

1. Instantiate an OAuth2 object and initialize it with the needed configuration
2. Monkey patch the `getOAuthAccessToken` method with our thingy
3. In our implementation, we're receiving the code and fetching the access token and refresh token.

You can also provide a callback and execute it instead of returning the OAuth2 object.